# How to pass filter value to workspace tiles query in Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-365

I am applying filter to tiles in workspace by using this code. But it didn't work as required because in datasource of query there are two fields "ContractID" and "OrignalContractID" both having extended type "OutboundContractID" and this filter is applying value on "OrignalContractID" field , but i want to apply it on "OutboundContractID" , so how can i achieve that.

```
        {              
            SysIFilterValue _contractIdFilter = SysFilterValueFactory::createFilterValueForString(element.parmLicenseContractID(), extendedTypeNum(OutboundContractID));
            filter.addItem(_contractIdFilter, SysFilterOperator::Equal, SysFilterValueResolutionMethod::None);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, however, I wanted to put an answer as I was recently working on this.  I have a workspace with Tiles and I wanted them to filter on the Workspace Filter I setup.  You can do this by giving your filter an EDT (In my case CustAccount), and then your tiles need to use the same EDT in their query (In my case this was CustTable as the top datasource).

Hope this helps.